# Removing Anti-Aliasing from shadows in the BGE

Tags: game-engine, light, opengl

How do I fix the anti-aliasing in edges of shadows in BGE?

[image: image of bad shadow]

Comment: shouldnt that be "Remove Aliasing from Shadows in the BGE" ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be solved relatively easily, but you may have to make minor changes elsewhere to keep the crisp shadow edge as pictured here, only without the anti-aliasing

This is the type of shadow that you have now.

[image: A blue cube with a bad looking shadow]

and I assume this is closer to what you want.

[image: A blue cube with a softer, better looking shadow]

You can achieve this simply be changing the shadow casting setting on your shadow emitting lamps from *Simple* to *Variance*

[image: a gif showing the setting change]

of course, now you can tweak the settings to restore the crisp shadow edge. I found that by squashing the *Bias,* the shadow looked much better.

[image: a gif showing more settings changing to make the shadow look even better]

You will need to make all your shadow lamps have the same settings for the final result to look good. It is usually a good idea to only have a  few shadow lamps, one main lamp for everything, and then extra spotlights as needed. A better approach is baking on the shadows for the environment, and then use a spotlight parented to the character to give your character dynamic shadows.